# Best way to index two "timestamp" columns

Tags: postgresql, indexing

How i should index two `timestamp` columns (ie `starts_at` and `ends_at`), which would be used almost always together in queries (like `starts_at >= ? AND ends_at <= ?`)? Create composite index for both columns or index each one separatly?

Btw, i'm using Postgres, if it matters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two columns are true timestamps with a low number of rows containing **precisely** the same timestamp, then there really is no use in a composite key, since the range scan would not be able to pick a single value for the first.  This can be different if the fields are dates, as frequently dates can match where timestamps don't.  There is a small benefit to it but my experience is that it's not enormous.

If you are using a sufficiently large and dense datase (if a single index scan will need to scan a large portion of the index) the query planner can use multiple indexes, combining them with a bitmap.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

As always with this type of question, it's worth running tests on your dataset.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, columns are true "timestamps without timezone". And amount of rows with precisely same values are ridiculously low. I'll try to use single indexes.

Answer (score 4):

This one's for posterity's sake as I see it was answered a long time ago. This assumes Postgres 9.2+. If you have a range of dates you should use `tsrange` as your data type:

```
create table events(
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique,
  duration tsrange not null
);
```

The nice thing about ranges is you can do some amazing queries with them, for your needs, this is the best part:

```
create index idx_event_duration on events
using GIST(duration);
```

Now you can query using all kinds of special operators:

```
select * from events where
duration @> (now() - interval '2 weeks');
```

[You can read more about them here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rangetypes.html). This barely scratches the surface of what they can do.